# How to fix "Overflow hidden" in Elementor "Custom position"

Tags: html, css, wordpress, elementor

I am trying to make a custom postition image on the right side of the page. Hiding the part sticking out. I use Elementor for wordpress with the custom postion function.

Page size: Tablet only

Here is a link to the page I am working on:
https://taskoftheday.com/how/

[image: What do fix]

I have tried the overflow:hidden css but no success.

```
max-width: 100%;
overflow-x: hidden;
```

I want to hide the overflowed part of the images sticking out to the right.

Comment: I think it is working now

Comment: @fmsthird Still got the issue. Check the screen width 950px :)

Comment: I see . let me check again

Comment: try to apply `overflow-x:hidden !important;` in the body tag itself to force hiding overflows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your **`custom css`** settings, try this syntax:

```
body {overflow-x:hidden !important;}
```

This will apply hiding `overflow` regardless of the screen size.

Answer (score 0):

There is now an option to hide the overflow. In the section layout setting you can select "hidden" as an option to "overflow".
https://elementor.com/blog/custom-positioning/ see this page for more info.